# Stubing sub methods in a tested Action Zend FramWork

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, zend-framework2

Using Zend FrameWork I'm testing an action in a controller class. unfortunately this action depends on some methods within the same controller class. I have tried to make a mocked object from the controller class, and stub the  methods but the tested action never takes it in consideration. what is the best way to stub these  methods?

Thanks.

Comment: If the actions are inside the same class, they don't need to be mocked. Only dependencies outside class-scope need to be mocked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. in fact I don't want those methods to return real values. i need only nulls to be returned. just like in this example:

[link](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-5-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/)

Comment: Well, you can not mix a real object and a mock at the same time, there is no sense doing that, or if you have to, you have testability and isolation issues. Method that should be mocked must be isolated from those which sould be tested.
The only way is to mock entirely your controller, which is totally useless, as you test a mock...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to clarify my question more. as you can in the link i've shared, there is that function called checkPassWord() that the tested function called (authorize()) uses. checkPassWord() exits when the value given is wrong. that's why another helper method was written called CallExit() that executes the exit. 
then to test the desired function (authorize()) we mock the class and let only CallExit() returns null as it is the only stub. while all the code in the other mocked functions is still executed. then we call the tested function from the mocked class. thanks.